# Turning for loop into lodash _.forEach

Tags: javascript, for-loop, lodash

I am trying to turn this

```
        _.forEach(dataset, function(items) {
          _.forEach(items, function(item) {
            for (var key in item) {
              if (key.indexOf('XX') === 0) {
                var toJsonVar = item[key];
                parseString(toJsonVar, function(err, res) {
                  item[key] = res;
                });
              }
            }
          });
        });
```

as you might see I have `_.forEach` from lodash on the first 2 scopes, but in the 3rd one I have a `for in` loop which I am trying to convert to lodash but I am getting an error.

```
            _.forEach(item, function(key)) {
              if (key.indexOf('XX') === 0) {
                var toJsonVar = item[key], toJsonRes;
                parseString(toJsonVar, function(err, res) {
                  item[key] = res;
                });
              });
```

there is the way I tried, what am I doing wrong ?

The error says

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

and the line of the error is

```
if (key.indexOf('XX') === 0) {
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @andersschuller sorry, see the update

Comment: Why not `_.forIn()` which would be more appropriate for iterating an object if you want to see key and value?

Comment: Why do you need this conversion? `for..in` in your case seems to be more readable.

Comment: Furthermore, you can use native [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of lodash's counterpart which only may be useful to ensure compatibility with old browsers.

Comment: There are a million options for iterating objects. Suggesting alternatives is not offering a solution to his question

Comment: Is your parseString async? Can you create a sync version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you're using `for (var key in item) {`, `key` is actually the **key** of the object, however in lodash `_.forEach`, the first parameter is the **value** in the object. Try this instead...

```
_.forEach(item, function(toJsonVar, key)) {
  if (key.indexOf('XX') === 0) {
     parseString(toJsonVar, function(err, res) {
       item[key] = res;
     });
  }
});
```

There is no longer any need to look up the value with `var toJsonVar = item[key]` because lodash has already passed it to your callback as the first parameter